# Remove Identical items/tuples from list

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples

I am trying to achieve the following:

I have two list with the same values.

```
a = ["A","B","C"]
b = ["A","B","C"]
```

I want to create pairs by crossing them, but removing identical values as below.

```
OUT = [("A","B"),("A","C"),("B","C")]
```

Is there any easy solution?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Itertools product without repeating duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314372/itertools-product-without-repeating-duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you don't need two lists to group elements. You can directly pass one of the lists to `itertools.combinations`:

```
list(combinations(a, 2))
```

where `a` is your list.

**Example**:

```
from itertools import combinations

a = ['A','B','C']

print(list(combinations(a, 2)))
# [('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('B', 'C')]
```