# Itertools without repetition but with multiple combinations

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

i can't seem to find a way to use itertools without repetitions *while* keeping multiple combinations.

*What I want* :

```py
> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
> the_result_i_want = ['ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb']
```

*What I manage to do so far :*

```py
for i in range (2, len(my_list)) : 
    for my_result in itertools.product(my_list, repeat=i) : 
        print(''.join(my_result))
```

but the result I currently have is `aa ab ac ba bb bc ca cb cc`
(i know it's a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314372/itertools-product-without-repeating-duplicates) but the answer considere that `ab` and `ba` are the same, which in my case should be different)
Thank you !

Comment: `itertools.permutations(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-do-i-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is one item below the documentation for `itertools.product`, namely `itertools.permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations

print([''.join(item) for item in permutations(my_list, 2)])
```

gives

```
['ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb']
```